# Culture-specific equivalent of ToString("0.0##")

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm changing my application to allow culture-specific numeric formatting, so I'm changing for instance `ToString("0.00")` to `ToString("F2")`.  However I don't see any standard way of doing an equivalent of `ToString("0.###")`.  How would I achieve that in a culture-specific way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the `.` in the format string just identifies the *placeholder* for the culture-specific decimal separator, so `ToString("0.###")` should work just fine. The same is true for the thousands separator `,` and the percent symbol `%`.

Proof:

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");

Console.WriteLine(1234.567.ToString("0.###",c));
```

output:

```
1234,567
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierPt) (emphasis added):

> The "." custom format specifier inserts a **localized decimal separator** into the result string. The first period in the format string determines the location of the decimal separator in the formatted value; any additional periods are ignored.
>
> The character that is used as the decimal separator in the result string is not always a period; it is determined by the [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object that controls formatting.

Comment: Wow, news to me!  Thanks a bunch.